# Bootstrap form validation - check that field is not blank, and includes valid URL

Tags: javascript, validation, bootstrap-4

I'm attempting to validate a Bootstrap 4.4 form field.  I don't just want to verify that this field is populated, I also want to verify that it's populated with a URL.  This can be an internal URL, a hostname or an IP address, however it should be entered as http://XXXXXX or https://XXXXXX, and must not be just XXXXX.com.  My current code (last section of this post) does not validate the form correctly.

Here's the html form that I'm starting with:

```
<form method="post" class="needs-validation">
<div class="input-group">
    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" class="form-control validationUrl" PLACEHOLDER="http://yourwebsite" required>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
            Looks good!
        </div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Must begin with http
        </div>
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT class="btn btn-primary" VALUE="GO">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

This in itself will prevent the form from being sumbitted blank.  I'm trying to test if the submitted value: 1. is not blank, and 2. is a URL (starting with http).

There are some useful Stack Overflow posts with URL validation code, like this one:
[JS Regex url validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970068/js-regex-url-validation)
which gives us the following code:

```
function isUrlValid(userInput) {
    var res = userInput.match(/(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g);
    if(res == null)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

I've then taken the starter bootstrap validation code found here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

```
<script>
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
'use strict';
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
    }, false);
    });
}, false);
})();
</script>
```

I've hacked together the following, however it's not doing any validation at all.  It will allow anything to be submitted.

**Current work in progress code I'm trying to fix:**

```
<form method="post" class="needs-validation">
<div class="input-group">
    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" class="form-control validationUrl" PLACEHOLDER="http://yourwebsite" required>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
            Looks good!
        </div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Must begin with http
        </div>
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT class="btn btn-primary" VALUE="GO">
    </div>
</div>
</form>


<script>
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
'use strict';
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('validationUrl');
    var res = userInput.match(/(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g);
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(res, function(res) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
    }, false);
    });
}, false);
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try this JS, and see if it works.

```js
`function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}`
```

### You then add the following to the form, which will call the function when the submit button is clicked.

```html
onsubmit="return validateForm()"
```

### the myform value is the name of the form and the fname value is the name of the input you wished to be checked.

### The logic of the if statement can be used to give a slew of validations. If you want to check if the first 7 characters of the input is something specific, you can use the substring class.

```js
    `function validateForm() {
      var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].substring(0,6);
      if (x !== "http://") {
        alert("please enter a valid URL");
        return false;
      }
    }`
```

Comment: for your third code snippet, I was able to make this work after changing substring(0,7).  0 is the first position.

Comment: Yes, it is 0 indexed. I will edit that when I get access to a computer again.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure the field is non-empty -> add `required` attribute.

To make sure it's a valid url -> Instead of `type="text"`, try the attribute `type="url"`

Sample: `<INPUT type="url" class="form-control validationUrl" placeholder="http://yourwebsite" required>`

Note: You can also add `pattern` attribute to make the url matching more strict.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url